# Check if values matchs in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to check with `mongodb` if `nickname` and `password` are `true` im trying to use the `$and` operator with `$regex` but I can't get it work. Can someone help me a hand with it currently have this;

```
checkNickname: function(nickname, password){
    var reNick = new RegExp(nickname, "i"),
        rePass = new RegExp(password, "i");
    getProfile.find( { $and :  [{
        nickname: { $ne: { $regex: reNick } } },
        { password: { $ne: { $regex: rePass} } } 
    ]}, function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it for you,

```
    checkNickname: function(nickname, password){
        var reNick = new RegExp("/^" + nickname + ".*/", "i"),
            rePass = new RegExp("/^" + password + ".*/", "i");
        getProfile.find({ 
                    nickname: { $not: reNick },  
                    password: { $not: rePass }
            }, function(err, data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mention you can't have [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) as argument to [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) but you can [negate your regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

```
checkNickname: function(nickname, password){
    var reNick = RegExp("^((?!"+nickname+").)*$", "i");
    var rePass = new RegExp("^((?!"+password+").)*$", "i");
    getProfile.find( { nickname: reNick, password: rePass }, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
};
```

Comment: find function takes two arguments, first is always err so it must be `function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(data)
    });`

Comment: With `data` as second argument I get now a array but its empty I think that means no match is found.

Comment: Yes that is what it means